# Factorization of Proth numbers with $k=1$

Tags: reference-request, prime-factorization

This is more of a practical question, for anyone out there who might know where to start. I'm looking for a complete factorization of numbers of the form $2^n+1$ for positive integers $n$. Essentially Proth numbers with $k=1$.

For small enough numbers, I can factorize them myself, but I was wondering if there is some dataset out there that would contain factorization of larger numbers of this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Cunningham tables](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/%7Essw/cun/index.html) for factorizations of the numbers $b^n \pm 1$

for
$b = 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12$, up to high powers $n$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Additionally, I've found that [prothsearch.com](http://www.prothsearch.com) contains some more data on this topic.